# No sound device in System settings -> sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, pavucontrol

Hallo i have a problem with my sound under the latest ubuntu release.

first there is no device in the system settings -> sound windows.

second there is no loudspeaker icon in the top tray.

third when i start pavucontrol, there is a label "Establishing connection to Pulseaudio". But the connection is never established.

I recently installed jack and cadence to run my external soundcard on my computer. now i deinstalled all the software i previously installed.

What can I do?

Comment: OK. I found something which solved the problem. In the terminal I entered the command line "pulseaudio -D". This started the pulseaudio server. Can somebody tell me how I can run this command automatically when I boot the system?